# Как добавить проверку входа пользователя в приложение для начала работы других функций

Tags: rust, webapi, actix-web

Я впервые работаю с api приложениями и тем более на языке rust. Появилась необходимость в проверке входа пользователя, есть некоторые функции программы которые должны начинать работу только после того как программа поймет, что пользователь вошел в аккаунт. Есть ли идеи как это можно сделать ? [image: Изображение функции приглашения в гитхаб после того как пользователь авторизуется]
На скриншоте изображена функция приглашения пользователя в гитхаб